# Blackberry webworks Hello World App, The SDK tool hangs in the browser

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

**Operating System & Environment:** Windows 7 Ultimate x64; I have [these](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/setting_up_your_tools.html) tools set up, as instructed by blackberry webworks.Used both Chrome browser Version 31.0.1650.63 m and firefox version 26.

**Background:** I am making my first attempt to use apache cordova. I have been doing my best to follow along with the documentation at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/.

**The Problem:** There is a guide for a simple hello world program located at https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/creating_your_first_app.html#kba1370890385302 and when I follow along, on step 5 of creating the project, the blackberry webworks SDK tool merely hangs in the browser forever, meanwhile the server in the command interface looks like this:

See This Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/BjCxHDfB

Furthermore, here is a screenshot of the application hanging, if it helps:

[image]

**Question:** What is causing this problem, and how can I fix it to successfully follow along with the sample hello world tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get some advice on the BlackBerry Development Forums, posted here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/WebWorks-Hello-World-tutorial-Webworks-SDK-tool-hangs-in-the/td-p/2729895

In summary, the blackberry webworks sdk GUI needed to be able to call the 'webworks' command from within the Command Console. In my setup, I was unable to call the 'webworks' command because I didn't have the environment variables properly set up.

My solution was uninstall the webworks SDK and then reinstall it, this time letting the installer put it in the default location, which was *C:\Program Files\BlackBerry\BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.54* . The installer automatically added the webworks environment variable WEBWORKS_HOME.

After doing these steps, I was then able to successfully run the blackberry WebWorks SDK Tool in accordance with the [Hello World Tutorial](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/creating_your_first_app.html).